# App Registration Role Deletion?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a requirement to delete some roles from an app registration.

Have tried to do this on the Azure portal both directly in the manifest editor and by downloading / editing / uploading the manifest JSON.

I get the following error:

> Failed to update application xxxxxx.  Error details:
>   CannotDeleteEnabledEntitlement.

I also tried to set "isEnabled" property to "false" and delete the roles after that with no success.

Anyone have any pointers on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the JSON file in this question? We need more details to find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your post, the deletion of any OAuth2Permission is a 2 step process:

1. You must first disable the permission, and push that to the directory.
2. Then you can delete the permission.

The error message you are showing in your post is a result of you not disabling the permission first. You will need to share details about the error you get if trying to delete the disabled permission fails as well.